# which one is best ORM for using in CMS based application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

which one is best ORM for using in CMS based application

Comment: possible duplicate of [What ORM for .net should I use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691575/what-orm-for-net-should-i-use)

Comment: There isn't an ORM that 'better fits' a CMS than any other ORM. If you're looking for an ORM for a .NET based solution, there are plenty of ones out there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146087/best-performing-orm-for-net http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206197/best-free-orm-tools-to-use-with-net-2-0-3-5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539429/best-orm-option-from-asp-net-mvc-to-mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249550/what-orm-frameworks-for-net-do-you-like-best http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691575/what-orm-for-net-should-i-use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for **Linq2Sql**.